# draw multiple curves in WinForms picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, draw

I am working on a program which I want to draw diode curves in a WinForms application. I have a list of diode names and I have theire points as you can see at the right side of the picture. That is Voltage as X and Current as Y ( A curve contains like 50 points).

What I want to do is by selecting one or more diodes from the list theire curve show up on my plot. What you see is just a picture box at the moment filled with a bmp. I know that this is not a reliable solution, so I am asking you what can be the best approach to do such thing? I dont know any good component which can make me do this. So I just need to know what can be the best approuch for this task?

[image: A quick view of what I want]

A diode curve is something like:

[image: Diode curve]

I might have up to 100 of diode curves in my program which all of them (single or multiple) should be drawn by clicking on them in the list.

So what you think?

**UPDATE**

**ALSO important thing is by deselecting a pin in the curve, its curve should be removed from the plot!**

I am drawing that axis you see using the code below:

```
    Bitmap xyCords = new Bitmap(500, 500);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(xyCords);
g.DrawLine(penAxis, 250, 0, 250, 500);
g.DrawLine(penAxis, 0, 250, 500, 250);
curveBox.Image = xyCords;
```

how is it possible later if I made a new Graphics I append it like:

```
curveBox.Image += newGraphic;
```

** Please let me know if there is any component or something which already can do what I want. or else show me a good approach! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Graphics.DrawCurve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ak09y3z.aspx).  You just put all of the points you want in an array, and pass that and a pen to the method.

**Edit:**
Add this after your code to prove to yourself that both graphs coexist.  To erase one or the other, just plot the same points, but in the background color of the bitmap (test for it, I don't remember what it is).

```
Point[] ptarray = new Point[3];
ptarray[0] = new Point(250, 250);
ptarray[1] = new Point(300, 300);
ptarray[2] = new Point(350, 400);

Pen pengraph = new Pen(Color.Green, 0.75F);
g.DrawCurve(pengraph, ptarray);

Point[] ptarray2 = new Point[3];
ptarray2[0] = new Point(100, 100);
ptarray2[1] = new Point(200, 150);
ptarray2[2] = new Point(250, 250);

Pen pengraph2 = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 1.25F);
g.DrawCurve(pengraph2, ptarray2);
```

Comment: @jonsca Hi, My questoin is I should do this on what basis? I think on a picturebox it is not good, as it can contain only 1 image as far as I know. I mean like that if you add only one curve is simple, but as soon as you already have one curve on the picturebox as a bmp, when you are going to add second curve to it you have to add that two at the same time again. Am I right?

Comment: No, because you will incorporate your bmp as a graphics object and you can do whatever painting and drawing is necessary.  Personally, if this aspect of it isn't your whole project, I would look into canned controls that already do the job of plotting (I don't know any offhand, but I'm sure there are plenty).

Comment: @jonsca ok I think you mean I can apply as many graphics I want to a picturebox? I am currently using this code to draw only the axis to my picture box: `Bitmap xyCords = new Bitmap(500, 500);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(xyCords);
g.DrawLine(penAxis, 250, 0, 250, 500);
g.DrawLine(penAxis, 0, 250, 500, 250);

curveBox.Image = xyCords;`   but you see I cant do later a new graphic and do like `curveBox += newBMP` this does not compile. can you give a little bit of code example please?

Comment: Yes, let me test it out for myself to make sure I'm not remembering incorrectly.  If what you say is the case, you can keep a jagged 2D array of all of your point arrays and repaint them each time.

Comment: @jonsca, I tried your way and made a class for this task, it seems to work :P but I am not sure if it is the best way but yeah it works!

Comment: The best way start to investigate a more effective way is to poke around an open source project (e.g., but not limited to, [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) and see how they do things.